# custom columns selection google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a google script to save a google sheet as a csv daily, I would like to only save desired columns (in this case columns 1,2,4,9,14,25,26 and 44).
I tried to modify the range, an if after columns loop, putting only the wanted columns as i value for columns loop... but the script still saves the whole google sheet. Any ideas ? Thanks

```
/*Sauvegarde de Stylez*/ 

function saveAsCSV_Stylez() {
  // Prompts the user for the file name
  var fileName = "CSV_Stylez"; //Browser.inputBox("Save CSV file as (e.g. myCSVFile):");
  // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
  fileName = fileName + ".csv";
  delteFile_Stylez(fileName);
  // Convert the range data to CSV format
  var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_Stylez(fileName);
  // Create a file in Drive with the given name, the CSV data and MimeType (file type)
  //DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile, MimeType.CSV);
  var CF = DriveApp.getFolderById('1D5NBqNRb7tdpfiiUyPM18cfMnPzhZHVl').createFile(fileName, csvFile, MimeType.CSV);
}
 
function convertRangeToCsvFile_Stylez(csvFileName) {
  // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('CSV_Stylez'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:AR3500').activate();
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined; 
    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }
 
        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}


function delteFile_Stylez(myFileName) {
  var allFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById('1D5NBqNRb7tdpfiiUyPM18cfMnPzhZHVl').getFilesByName(myFileName);
  while (allFiles.hasNext()) {
    var thisFile = allFiles.next();
    thisFile.setTrashed(true);
  };
  function convertRangeToCsvFileCSV_LAD(csvFileName) {
  // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('CSV_Stylez'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:AR3500').activate();
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined; 
    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }
         
        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = ws.getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var expectedColumns = [1, 2, 4, 9, 14, 25, 26, 44]; // This column numbers is from your question.
var data = ws.getValues().map(r => expectedColumns.map(e => r[e - 1]));
```

- In this modification, after the values were retrieved with `ws.getValues()`, the columns are selected.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks, tried a .map also but obviously i didn't set it correctly. Works perfect thanks !

Comment: @MaxM Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.